# javascript and jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am new to Java. I have a HTML which has a show users button, on clicking this button I want to redirect the user to the `users.jsp` page. How do I achieve that? Will a function like this help?

```
function msg()
{
 alert("List of Users");<br/>
 jsp:forward page="Users.jsp"<br/>
}
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript have nothing whatsoever in common. Like car is to card.

Comment: they are somewhat syntacticly similar. and they are both programming languages, but javascript is a 'scripting' language. I too am tired of people confusing the two, but it's only to be expected.

Answer (score 4):

Java and JavaScript are two entirely distinct languages which runs each on its own environment. Java/JSP runs at the webserver machine, produces template text including HTML/CSS/JS and sends it over network to the client side as a HTTP response. Once arrived at the client machine, the webbrowser starts to display HTML, apply CSS and interpret/execute JS. If Java/JSP has done its job well, you should not see any line of Java/JSP code in the obtained HTML source (rightclick page > *View Source*).

The only way to let Java/JSP do something with JavaScript is to generate/print it accordingly that it get interpreted/executed in the client side the way you want. The only way to let JavaScript do something with Java/JSP code is to let it fire a HTTP request to an URL on which a JSP file or a Java Servlet listens and then exectues accordingly. You can fire a HTTP request with `form.submit()`, `window.location` and `new XMLHttpRequest()` (which is the base idea of Ajax).

In your particular case, you can just use `window.location`:

```
function msg() {
   alert('List of Users');
   window.location = 'Users.jsp';
}
```

or if this button is part of a `<form>`, then just specify it in the form action:

```
<form action="Users.jsp" onclick="msg()">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

with

```
function msg() {
   alert('List of Users');
}
```

To learn more about the wall between Java/JSP and JavaScript, you may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) useful. As to learning Web Development in general, you may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543091/where-to-start-from-in-web-development/1843841#1843841) useful and for Java Web Development [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/1958854#1958854).

Answer (score 1):

=) first thing to learn: java != javascript

anyway, here's a nice function for you

```
function msg() {
    alert("List of Users");
    location.href = "users.jsp";
}
```

and the accompanying HTML

```
<button onclick="msg()">Click Me!</button>
```

good luck

===edit===

Full HTML page:

```
<html>
<head><title>Hi</title></head>
<body>

<script>
    function msg() {
        alert("List of Users");
        location.href = "users.jsp";
    }
</script>
<button onclick="msg()">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Essentially, if you print that ^ out in your servelet, you will get the desired result.

Comment: hi jared,
thanks for the quick reply. Can you tell me whats the best way to get a pop-up in jsps/servelets.

Comment: I assume you want the popup to appear in the browser? Your servelet outputs HTML, which is then interpreted by the browser. -- see my edit for some example HTML

Answer (score 1):

If you are more comfortable with Java than Javascript, perhaps [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/overview.html) would be a desirable option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot embed JSP in JavaScript, because JavaScript is ran by the browser, and browser does not implement JSP.

Try `window.location = "Users.jsp";` in JavaScript.