# Where we have to put the .class file in Tomcat Directory

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Where do I have to put my `*.class` file in Tomcat Directory?

In my Java-Complete Reference book, they told to put it in `C:\Program Files\Apache Tomcat 4.0\webapps\examples\WEB-INF\classes`. But now i'm using Tomcat 7.0. There is no folder exists with the name "examples" in webapps.

How can I fix this? Can you tell me links that will illustrate Servlets from beginning?

Comment: have you actually compiled anything? and are you using an IDE?

Comment: i just typed the code from the book and compiled in cmd prompt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create one yourself. Any folder which you create in `Tomcat/webapps` will become a standalone webapplication. You don't even need to name it explicitly `/examples`. You can even name it `/beer`. You then just have to change the URL from http://localhost:8080/examples  to http://localhost:8080/beer.

---

That said, I think it's better to look for a more recent book than the one mentioning Tomcat 4.0 which is already over a decade old. There might be more old fashioned advices/practices in the book which really can't be done anymore nowadays (for example, cough, [*scriptlets*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)). Those books are more recent (in order from newest to older):

- [Murach Servlets and JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890774448)
- [Head First Servlets & JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516681)
- [Core Servlets and JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130092290)

To learn JSP/Servlets online, I can recommend the tutorials and ebook at coreservlets.com:

- [Beginning and intermediate JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)
- [Advanced JSP/Servlet tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html)
- [Core Servlets and JSP ebook](http://pdf.coreservlets.com/)

#### See also:

- [Java EE web development, what skills do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/1958854#1958854)
- [Servlet lifecycle and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909)

Comment: +1 I actually like the webapp named *beer*. If only it served up the appropriate response.