# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, file-upload

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm) for using servlet for file upload.

Here is the folder structure (Dynamic project created using Eclipse). I am NOT using maven for this simple project. I added the external jar to the build path.

[image]

when I start Tomcat and deploy this application by right-clicking on the project in Eclipse > Run on Server I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItemFactory
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    ... 20 more
```

please help me with what is going wrong here and how to fix this?

Comment: Did you made a Dynamic Web Project Version 3.0? You can check this info with : `right click on project> Project Facets`.

Comment: I do not see any Facets option. But I think it is 3.0 version from web.xml

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to copy the required *commons* jars into your `/WEB-INF/lib` folder as well.

```
commons-io-2.4.jar
commons-fileupload-1.3.1.jar
```

The reason is that just adding the jar dependencies to your Eclipse project's build path does not make them automatically available on Tomcat. Since, the dependencies are missing (not found in the `lib` folder) your web app's deployment fails.

Comment: this helped. but where are th class files (in this case UploadServlet.class) is stored. I looked into webapps folder but I do not see any context for UploadFileServlet(The project name as shown above)

Comment: May be you cant see the class files directly from Eclipse, But it is stored in folder TARGET/CLASS/.   you can see the class file by exploring these folders(WORKSPACE/PROJECT/TARGET/CLASS)

Comment: @anptk: I want to know where tomcat keeps context folder that it serves. usually, `.war` files are put in webapps folder of tomcat.  I do know where Eclipse puts the class files.

Comment: This may help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405121/where-we-have-to-put-the-class-file-in-tomcat-directory

Comment: @anptk: I am able to run the servlet from right clicking on eclipse. But when I go into webapps folder, I do not see my project directory (uploadFileServlet) there which will serve as context root.

Comment: @brainstorm Open the "Server" view and doubleclick on your server. Check the server location and deploy path. Eg:- D:\workingfiles\spring_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\StrutsLoginExample\WEB-INF\classes\com