# Should I learn Java before JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I have the opportunity for a new job in which I'd be moving from PHP to JSP. I've done a little java in the past but am just wondering if I should revise my java knowledge before attempting to learn JSP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are going to write **business logic** too (not only **views** in JSP), then knowing the Java language is required.

On the other hand, if somebody else codes all the business logic for you, and all you are left with is objects injected into your JSP, you might get away with just using [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html) alone to control the formatting of your views. (i.e, no [scriptlets](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/tags/11/syntaxref11.fm5.html) in your views)

Comment: Thanks Bakkal! I think as a minimum I'm going to get my existing knowledge back up to scratch

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. JSP should not contain any line of raw Java code. But you'd like to learn Java before learning Servlets. That is where you write Java code in.

#### See also:

- [Java web development, what skills do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need)
- [How to avoid Java code in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/howto-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 1):

I hardly come across projects based only on JSP, mostly the servlets are pure java code and some logic is implemented in the JSPs for tables, ..

Refreshing java-knowledge for pure JSP projects is always a plus, but not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

For simple scripts, it's not necessary. But if you want to do something more complex, you are going to need servlets and others java classes, so you are going to need learn Java.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to work on your java basics as some times you need to take help from core java classes as per requirement.

JSP is not same like PHP. most of the frameworks of the jsp or J2EE are using POJO (Plain Old Java Objects) which are need to written in core Java classes.

I had worked on PHP for 2 years now working on Java. Mainly on core java is as much useful in JSP programming.

For playing with forms you no need to have Core Java competency. But for Enterprise Solutions you require it.