# Displaying .gif file in JSP form using Servlet program

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have written a servlet java program.

During the execution of one particular loop of the program, I need the a gif file to be displayed in the JSP form indicating that the process is going on.

I am not aware of implementing the same inside the loop.

Kindly advise on how the same has to be done, such that a gif file is displayed in the JSP form and it would be of great use if u can suggest any .gif file for the purpose of processing display. Am a beginner in java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSP is supposed to output HTML. Images in HTML are to be displayed using `<img>` tag. This tag has a `src` attribute which is supposed to point to a public web resource. Here's an example:

```
<img src="progress.gif">
```

When opening the JSP page by http://example.com/context/page, this assumes the `progress.gif` file to be present in http://example.com/context/progress.gif (i.e. in the root of the public webcontent folder).

Now, you want to display the image only when the submit button is pressed in order to wait for the response to be finished. You can do this by initially hiding the image using CSS and redisplaying it using JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="showProgress()">
<img id="progress" src="progress.gif">
```

CSS:

```
#progress { 
    display: none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function showProgress() {
    document.getElementById('progress').style.display = 'block';
}
```

When the response is finished, it will refresh the page with the new target page and the progress image will "automatically" disappear.

---

**Update**: here's how the complete JSP file can look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <style>
            #progress { 
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            function showProgress() {
                document.getElementById('progress').style.display = 'block';
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" onclick="showProgress()">
            <img id="progress" src="progress.gif">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or when CSS/JS is externalized in its own file (recommended):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="submit" onclick="showProgress()">
            <img id="progress" src="progress.gif">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### See also:

- [HTML tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/)
- [Where to start from in web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543091/where-to-start-from-in-web-development/1843841#1843841)
- [Java Webdevelopment - What skills do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/1958854#1958854)

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I am confused on how to integrate the CSS/JavaScript into my Servlet Java program.

Comment: Or where must be the CSS/JavaScript contents placed exactly?

Comment: Either directly in the JSP file by `<style>` and `<script>` tags respectively, or in an external `.css` and `.js` file which you then include in HTML `<head>` by `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` and `<script src="script.js"></script>` respectively. In an external file is best choice on long term (maintainability, reusability and so on). Those files should of course be available by public webcontent (or at least an by intermediating servlet). I'd suggest to get yourself through a basic HTML tutorial as well. This has nothing to do with JSP/Servlet.

Comment: More than saying a Thanks this time too, I would like to add, You're are really genius BalusC and kind-hearted in helping me out in almost all questions that I have posted. Thanks for your elaborate answers BalusC.