# JFileChooser not working with Servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, jfilechooser

My code is working fine (choosing directory) when used in the main method. However, using the same code copied into a servlet, isn't working, what should I do to get this to work with servlet?

```
public class SelectDirectory {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, Exception {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("choosertitle");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            String dirFolder = "" + chooser.getSelectedFile() + "";
            FunctionsOfZip zipFun = new FunctionsOfZip();
            zipFun.InputReader(dirFolder);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: What should that do? Open a FileChooser window on the web server? Usually, those don't have a monitor (or a person) attached to them.

Comment: a servlet runs on the server side. that 'll cause some trouble trying to run something like this through servers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4502422/1031945

Comment: @Stultuske, then there is no posibility of running this code using servlet?

Comment: of course it will run. but the client won't get the FileChooser, it will "run" on the server machine. and, as Thilo said: those usually don't have a monitor attached, or a person observing them, so nobody would notice. even if somebody noticed it, it would be running on the wrong system

Answer (score 2):

`JFileChooser` is for Swing Application. `Servlet` is running on Server side. At client side there is browser which has HTML  `input` type named `file`. This file input will open the directory of client to select file for upload.

```
 <form>
 <input type="file"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: Masud,how can i integrate this with servlet,could you please give me an idea?

Comment: @ThazAhammad, you should write this portion of code to JSP. At servlet, you can also write it on `PrintWriter#print` method.

Comment: Can anybody help me according to Masud technique.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write in your JSP page an input param with `type="file"` , then haldle it in your servlet.

This [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm) may help you.