# Creating Menubar in jsp

Tags: html, css, jsp

How can we create menubar in jsp. We have to use html commands, or is there any other method? If anybody can give me any web address where i can find the turorial for this. I have searched the web but unable to find any good answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to realize that JSP is just a Java based view technology which enables outputting HTML/CSS/JS dynamically and that HTML is a markup language which can instruct the webbroser how to display the page elements.

As to your problem, you need the HTML `<ul>` element to represent a list. Then you can apply a good shot of CSS to style it the way you want. This is in HTML/CSS world also called "Suckerfish dropdowns".

Since the question is too broad, best I can do is to recommend you the separate concepts "HTML" and "CSS" properly and give you some tutorial links.

- [W3schools HTML tutorial/reference](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)
- [W3schools CSS tutorial/reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)
- [Alistapart - Suckerfish dropdowns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns)
- [HTML dog - Suckerfish dropdowns](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/)

#### Related questions:

- [Where to start from in web development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543091/where-to-start-from-in-web-development/)
- [Java web development, what skills do I need?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/1958854#1958854)

Comment: Is there any plugin or package with the help of which I can create some standard horizontal menus. I have searched the web and most of the places javascript is used for menu creation.

Comment: I would have used [PrimeFaces Menubar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/menubar.jsf). However, it's based on top of [JSF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp) and another steep learning curve, certainly if you already aren't familiar with basic JSP/HTML/CSS/JS as proven by this question. If you are open to using jQuery (a brilliant JavaScript library), then checkout the many available [menu plugins](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+menu+plugin).