# Java EE Website Tutorials

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am looking for a Java EE Website with tutorials on how to build a real application (like [ASP.net's website](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store-part-1). Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC's equivalent in Java EE world is called "JSF". So now you have probably a more clear area to concentrate on (PS: "J2EE" has been upgraded to "Java EE" over 5 years ago.. keep yourself up to date).

Comment: @BalusC  Yep. But our course right now is J2EE (the older version) not Java EE. And it covers only Servlets/JSP/EJB  :( I'll study JavaEE after I finish J2EE.

Comment: I already deleted this Question and when I created another question this one also appears!

Comment: No, I just copypasted it. 10k users can see deleted questions.

Comment: @BalusC JavaEE is so big! How did u know what to use in a particular situation? Did you study everything? How long did you  study it? Where did u start? I want to be like u. :)

Comment: 10 years and counting. I started with HTML. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need/1958854#1958854) may be useful. Just follow the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out appfuse: http://appfuse.org/display/APF/Home

Appfuse creates for you a skeleton project, allowing you to specify the web application framework. The instructions seem ok, and the generated project also follows some best practices and provides some goodies.