# Java Servlet and Java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

What's the difference between Java Servlet and core Java? Is that difficult to learn Java Servlet assuming some background in Java programming?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2095397/what-is-the-difference-between-jsf-servlet-and-jsp) and eventually [Java Web development, what skills do I need?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need)

Comment: try doing a search, before you post a question!

Comment: Have you chosen a server that you would like to use? If all you are trying to make is a simple web application Tomcat may be pretty good to look into. However, Jetty is great for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [servlet](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html) is an interface from [this](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/package-summary.html) package.  I think you really are looking for the difference between JavaEE and core Java. Since the implementations of the JavaEE packages are written in java it should not be that difficult to learn.

[This](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/firstcup/doc/gkhoy.html) gives a fairly good and brief description of the difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

Java Servlet programming is the use of the `javax.servlet.*` family of classes to provide a dynamic java-based web service.  You program it using Java and they are not difficult to learn, however it's much easier to implement most functionality using JSP/JSF (which themselves are implemented using Servlets) as it's easier to edit the content.