# retrieve dropdown list from mysql database and insert to database in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

This thing is really bothering me. How can I get my dropdown list from MySQL database and then submit it to another table in JSP. I only know how to create a static dropdown with html   and  but how can I make it dynamic. I am thinking of a form that links to a servlet and the servlet connects to the database and fetches an array of strings from a database table and then sends it to the JSP to populate the  options and when an option is submitted, it send to a servlet which then inserts to the database. someone please give me some sample code that can do this. Most specifically I need the code of the JSP used in the  tag and the code for sending from the servlet. I've really checked with google but there is no clear answer. Hope I get an answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've it almost right. To get the dropdown values from a database you should first call the servlet which does the preprocessing job and then let the servlet display the JSP with the dropdown.

Since a normal HTTP request (clicking a link, a bookmark or entering the URL in address bar) fires per definition a GET request, you'd like to do the job in the `doGet()` method. Here's an example which gets the dropdown values in flavor of a `List<Product>`.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    List<Product> products = productService.list();
    request.setAttribute("products", products); // It'll be available as ${products}.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/products.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

In `/WEB-INF/products.jsp` you can display it as follows:

```
<form action="order" method="post">
    <select name="productId">
        <c:forEach items="${products}" var="product">
            <option value="${product.id}">${product.name}</option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Order" />
</form>
```

Map this servlet on an URL pattern of `/products` and invoke it by http://example.com/context/products. It'll load the products from the DB, store it in the request scope, forward to the JSP to let it present it.

When you submit the form, then the `doPost()` method of a servlet which is mapped on an URL pattern of `/order` will be invoked. When you submit a HTML form, then the `name=value` pair of every input element will be available as a HTTP request parameter. So you can get the product ID as follows:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String productId = request.getParameter("productId");
    // ... do your job here to insert the data.

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/someresult.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our JSP wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)
- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)

Comment: Thank you @BalusC. I understand the code you've given but this line is not clear to me`List<Product> products = productService.list();
`. Please explain it. I don't see the actual values being sent to the JSP

Comment: `ProductService` is just your class which uses JDBC code to get data from the DB the usual JDBC way and returns it in flavor of a `List<Product>`. Servlet doesn't send anything to JSP. The servlet just stores it as a request attribute with the name `"products"` and forwards the request to the JSP. The JSP in turn accesses the request attribute by `${products}`.

Comment: Thanks again @BalusC. can you give a sketchy code of that method definition, for example the part that returns because I don't get when you say "returns it in flavor of a List<Product>". I really don't know the use of List class.

Comment: Uhm, that brings us back to the very basics. I'd suggest to invest time in learning [basic Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) before diving into [Java web development](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1958808). If you also don't know SQL, then learn that first as well. Once you know Java and SQL, then learn [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) how to execute SQL language using Java code. Anyway, you can find here an article with learn-by-example samples: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html

Comment: Yah, I've come across DTOs and DAOs but not bothered to understand what really happens. Let me check out the link and do some more reading. I'll keep you posted @BalusC.

Comment: It is done. I read the link above DAOs and DTOs above and I created a DAO to access my database and select the values returning a list. The DTO was just a simple java bean with a getter method. I was then able to use the DTO in the JSP and retrieve the list using JSTL forEach and EL and on submission the form action invoked a servlet that inserted to the database. Only thing I didn't do was to use datasource and naming to access the database like the link shows. I used the usual connection means using drivermanager. I'll do more reading on that first. Thank you very much @BalusC.