# JSP Connect to Oracle with specific requirement

Tags: oracle, jsp, jdbc

I want to retrieve data from Oracle Data Base which has SID, Port, Host Name, User ID, Password, Data Base Name, but i don't know the format to get the data from table.
Could you give me code how to get data from table, for example let just say SID = _SID , Table= _Table, Column = _Column. Thank You.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: maybe just like this one :
`String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";`
I have tried many codes that i got, but it always got error, if you could give me the exact format, you have my thanks, but please be nice :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257114/getting-error-while-trying-to-fill-html-dropdown-with-mysql-data-in-java/9257203#9257203

Comment: there were error in this line `Connection connection= DriverManager.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.104:3306/networkmonitoring','mohsin','123456');")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) API to connect and execute the SQL statements. Take a look at [JDBC Oracle FAQ](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/JDBC).

Comment: i'm using JSP, so i should use KPRB driver correct? But where i should place the Username and Password, etc? thank you :)

Comment: @Nore From the JDBC Oracle FAQ - Oracle's JDBC KPRB driver is mainly used for writing Java stored procedures, triggers and database JSPs. It uses the default/ current database session and thus requires no additional database username, password or URL.

Comment: Oh, my bad. So i should use the Thin one and learn more in JDBC Oracle FAQ , thank you and sorry i'm just a newbie