# When to select a category from drop down, then I want it's subcategory in other drop down?

Tags: javascript

In this image I want to select category then I want subcategory in another drop down. On selecting value in Category I want to call Ajax which fetch subcatcategory from database and put it into another subcategory drop down. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [retrieve dropdown list from mysql database and insert to database in jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168836/retrieve-dropdown-list-from-mysql-database-and-insert-to-database-in-jsp)

Comment: Title is still undecipherable, but maybe other will have the time to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the client side, you need to get the data from the database through the server. You can read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168836/retrieve-dropdown-list-from-mysql-database-and-insert-to-database-in-jsp) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

In your view page call a ajax function where are want to change sub category on chage category

```
    $(document).on('change', '#cat_id', function () {
      var cat_id = $(this).val();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo site_url('controller_name/subCatByCatId'); ?>', // here call your function where you want to send cat_id
        data: {cat_id: cat_id},
        success: function (data) {
            $('#sub_cat_id').html(data);
        }
       });
     });
```

And here is your server side function

```
    function subCatByCatId() {
    $cat_id = $_POST['cat_id'];
    $query = $this->db->query("select * from sub_category where   cat_id=$cat_id")->result();//here replace your query 
     $returnVal = '<option value = "">Select one</option>';
     if (!empty($query)) {
         foreach ($query as $row) {
             $returnVal .= '<option value = "' . $row->sub_cat_id . '">'  . $row->sub_cat_name . '</option>';
         }
     }
     echo $returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: I am using spring MVC .

Comment: well its not matter if you can understand it hope you can implement in your project

Comment: you just  here `url: '<?php echo site_url('controller_name/subCatByCatId'); ?>',` call your controller and function

Comment: you are welcome bro if its help you so  accept my answer  :)