# How does this work? Java Date, Calendar and Richface question

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have noticed that numerous `Date` methods in Java have been deprecated, but rather most people tell me to use `Calender`.

Here is my problem. I am trying to create a `Calendar` where you can select a date and within Java set the date. So I have

```
public class someClass
{

    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    public void setStartDate(Date date) 
    {
        this.startDate = date;
    }

    public void setEndDate(Date date) 
    {
        this.endDate = date;
    }   

    public Date getStartDate()
    {
        return this.startDate;
    }

    public Date getEndDate() 
    {
        return this.end;
    }

}
```

with the RichFaces code

```
<rich:calendar popup="true" mode="ajax"  value="#{someClass.startDate}"/>
```

When I manually set it up in code it seems to show up, but when I change to a different date it never sets the date.

I have also seen that within calendars they tell me to use
`Calendar`. But when I type in `Calenders.Time.` it's not in Java, is it because it's protected? How does it work with RichFaces? Can RichFaces access it?

Comment: Your concrete problem has **nothing** to do with those deprecated methods of `Date`.

Comment: You did create an instance of `someClass` or register it as a managed bean right? Note that commonly class names start with a capital letter, e.g. `SomeClass`.

Comment: Yeah I was just using that as an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the concrete question of *"How to use `java.util.Calendar` with `<rich:calendar>`?"*, just bind the component to `Calendar#getTime()` which in turn returns a fullworthy `java.util.Date`.

E.g.

```
public class Bean {

    private Calendar startDate;

    public Bean() {
        startDate = Calendar.getInstance(); // You need to prepopulate it.
    }

    // ...
}
```

with

```xml
 <rich:calendar value="#{bean.startDate.time}" />
```

But that will **not** solve the *real* problem of the value not being set in the model. This is caused by something else. Don't get mislead by the deprecated methods of `Date`. Using `Date` in `<rich:calendar>` is perfectly fine. You only shouldn't be using those deprecated methods to set the year/month/day/etc of the date programmatically *yourself* like as in bean's constructor.

Your *real* problem can have many causes. Perhaps the `<rich:calendar>` isn't been placed in a `<h:form>`? Perhaps you're nesting multiple `<h:form>` components? Perhaps you've somewhere an `immediate="true"`? Perhaps you're grabbing/debugging the value at the wrong moment? Etc..etc..

Comment: question, what do you mean its in h:form? I'm pretty new at this or maybe what is immediate = true? I literally don't have much code around the calender besides the one i just showed

Comment: Well, that explains it. You need a `<h:form>` around it in order to be able to submit the input value along HTTP POST to the server. I'd say, put JSF aside for a while and take some time to learn HTML, HTML forms and HTTP (and preferably later also Servlets) to grasp the basic concepts. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need. JSF is basically a HTML code generator. Rightclick page in browser, *View Source* and look. Any HTML `<input>` element is supposed to be inside a HTML `<form>` element.

Comment: well. that makes sense... lol I didn't know i had to do that. Thanks!

Comment: What books/tutorials are you using to learn JSF? JSF has a relatively steep learning curve, definitely for ones who aren't already familiar with basic HTTP/HTML/Servlets. Please ensure that you're having/reading the proper ones. Otherwise you will still pull out your hairs after one year or two and unnecessarily rant on JSF for remnant of your life.

Comment: I just started a job and kind of got thrown into that. I don't do much web development, but I do a lot of .net in my previous jobs. This is actually my first permanent job. so that's why, btw what did you mean by immediate = true? what is it  suppose to do?

Comment: As to `immediate="true"`, check this: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html True, it's JSF 1.2 targeted, but the principles are not different for JSF 2.0 (which you're supposed to use nowadays). As to the learning materials, please grab yourself a good book. "JSF (2.0): The Complete Reference" is decent.

Comment: I've tried numerous things, added the h:form, added the immediate, nothing's working for me. this is sooo stressful.

Comment: You've got to provide more information than "it doesn't work". Ask a new question wherein you tell in detail the exact JSF and RichFaces versions you're using (e.g. Mojarra 2.1.2 with RichFaces 4.0.0) and provide the smallest possible view (from `<html>` until with `</html>`) and model (the backing bean) which exhibits your problem.

Comment: Okay. So, Stupid mistake. i forgot to add @In. Two letters ruined a day for me.