# Building my first Java Web Application

Tags: java, web-applications

I have to build a java web application and I'm not sure where to start.

I have a good amount of experience with java but I would like to know if anybody can point me to a good example of how to integrate java into a web page?

I searched google without much luck.  Is there a decent example on how to do this?  Is it similar to adding a flash object with an object tag?  Thanks

Comment: Googling "Java Web Application" gives quite a few hints on where to start.  It is *not* similar to adding a flash object with an object tag.

Comment: Server-side or client-side application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java web development, what skills do I need?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958808/java-web-development-what-skills-do-i-need)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start creating sample web application based on html and servlets, This site will guide you in doing so.

http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/simple-servlet-example.html

You will need

JDK
Apache Tomcat(jars will be in tomcat so no need to download separatly)

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for that.

http://www.appfuse.org

> AppFuse is an open source project and application that uses open source tools built on the Java platform to help you develop Web applications quickly and efficiently. It was originally developed to eliminate the ramp-up time found when building new web applications for customers. At its core, AppFuse is a project skeleton, similar to the one that's created by your IDE when you click through a wizard to create a new web project.

Answer (score 0):

You ahould start searching about :

1. Servlets (and Apache Tomcat)
2. JSP
3. Java Faces (and Apache MyFaces)
4. Existing web frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is to download Netbeans for Java EE with Glassfish, install it and use a wizard to create your first Hello World web application.

Then I recommend learning Spring MVC - I think it is the easiest to start with and very flexible so you can add more and more functionalities later. For templating, I recommend FreeMarker or Velocity.