# Tabs in JSF page are not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem which I cannot solve. When I open JSF tab and I try to click on the buttons the page is not working.

Main page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <ui:insert name="header">           
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>         
        </ui:insert>
        <style type="text/css">
            .settingsHashMap { font: 80% "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;}
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h1><img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" /> Rack Management Center</h1>
        <!-- layer for black background of the buttons -->
        <div id="toolbar" style="margin: 0 auto; width:100%; height:30px; position:relative;  background-color:black">
            <!-- Include page Navigation -->
            <ui:insert name="Navigation">           
                <ui:include src="Navigation.xhtml"/>         
            </ui:insert>
        </div>  
        <div id="logodiv" style="position:relative; top:35px; left:0px;"> 
            <h:graphicImage alt="Datacenter Profile" style="position:relative" value="resources/images/logo_datacenter_profile.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="main" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:700px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:105px">

            <div id="mainpage" style="margin: 0 auto; width:1190px; height:500px; position:absolute;  background-color:transparent; top:80px">

                <div id="settingsHashMapz" class="settingsHashMap" style="width:1150px; height:400px; position:absolute; top:20px; left:1px">

                    <h:form prependId="false">
                        <h:panelGroup id="tabs" layout="block">
                            <ul>
                                <c:forEach items="#{DatacenterProfileController.tabs}" var="tab">
                                    <li><a href="##{tab.tabid}" onclick="$('#button_#{tab.tabid}').click()">#{tab.tabid}</a></li>
                                    <h:commandButton id="button_#{tab.tabid}" value="TabClick" action="#{DatacenterProfileController.switchPages(tab.tabid)}" style="display:none">
                                        <f:ajax render="tabs"></f:ajax>
                                    </h:commandButton>  
                                </c:forEach>
                            </ul>

                            <c:forEach items="#{DatacenterProfileController.tabs}" var="tab">
                                <h:panelGroup id="#{tab.tabid}" layout="block" rendered="#{tab.tabid eq DatacenterProfileController.selectedTab}">
                                    <ui:include src="#{tab.tabfilename}"></ui:include>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </c:forEach>

                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:form>

                </div>   

            </div>  
        </div>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Tab page:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <ui:composition>
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:form id="zones" >
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" />
                    <!-- The sortable data table -->
                    <h:dataTable onmouseover="addOnclickToTabsDatatableRows();" id="dataTable" headerClass="columnHeader" value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.dataList}" binding="#{zones}" var="item">
                        <!-- Check box -->
                        <h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox style="margin-left: 0px;" value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.mainSelectAll}" class="checkall" >
                                    <f:ajax listener="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.selectAll}" render="@form" />
                                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  onclick="highlight(this)" value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.selectedIds[item.datacenterid]}" >
                                <!-- if the user deselects one row deselect the main checkbox -->
                                <f:ajax listener="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.deselectMain}" render="@form" />
                            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
                            <!-- Click on table code -->  
                            <h:outputLink id="lnkHidden" value="ZoneProfile.jsf" style="text-decoration:none; color:white; background-color:black">
                                <f:param name="id" value="#{item.datacenterid}" />
                            </h:outputLink>
                        </h:column>
                        ............

                    </h:dataTable>

                    <!-- The paging buttons -->
                    <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="first" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pageFirst}"
                                     disabled="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.firstRow == 0}" >
                        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>&nbsp;

                    <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="prev" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pagePrevious}"
                                     disabled="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.firstRow == 0}" >
                        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>&nbsp;

                    <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="next" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pageNext}"
                                     disabled="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.firstRow + DCProfileTabZonesController.rowsPerPage >= DCProfileTabZonesController.totalRows}" >
                        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>&nbsp;    

                    <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="last" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pageLast}"
                                     disabled="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.firstRow + DCProfileTabZonesController.rowsPerPage >= DCProfileTabZonesController.totalRows}" >
                        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>&nbsp;

                    <h:outputText value="Page #{DCProfileTabZonesController.currentPage} / #{DCProfileTabZonesController.totalPages}" />
                    <br />

                    <!-- The paging links -->
                    <ui:repeat value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pages}" var="page">
                        <h:commandLink value="#{page}" actionListener="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.page}"
                                       rendered="#{page != DCProfileTabZonesController.currentPage}" style="text-decoration:none;color:white;">
                            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>   
                        </h:commandLink>
                        <h:outputText value="#{page}" escape="false"
                                      rendered="#{page == DCProfileTabZonesController.currentPage}" style="text-decoration:none;color:gray;"/>
                    </ui:repeat>
                    <br />

                    <!-- Set rows per page -->
                    <h:outputLabel for="rowsPerPage" value="Rows per page" />
                    <h:inputText id="rowsPerPage" value="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.rowsPerPage}" size="3" maxlength="3" />
                    <h:commandButton styleClass="bimage" value="Set" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.pageFirst}" >
                        <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>&nbsp;
                    <h:message for="rowsPerPage" errorStyle="color: red;" />

                    <!-- hidden button -->
                    <h:commandButton id="deleterow" value="HiddenDelete" action="#{DCProfileTabZonesController.deleteSelectedIDs}" style="display:none">
                        <f:ajax render="@form"></f:ajax>
                    </h:commandButton>

                    <!-- the delete button -->
                    <h:button styleClass="bimage" value="Delete" onclick="deletedialog(this, 'Do you want to delete the selected rows?'); return false;" />&nbsp;

                    <!-- New Zone -->
                    <h:button id="newzone" styleClass="lbimage" value="New Zone" outcome="/NewZone.xhtml"/>

                    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/js/tabs.js"></script> 
                </h:form>         
            </h:panelGroup>
        </ui:composition>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

When I remove the `ui:composition` tag and I insert all the code into one page the buttons are working.

Comment: Please read last point of "Information to provide" in [our JSF wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info). A lot of your questions (and of [your colleague or clone account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1285928/user1285928)) are been ignored or hardly properly answered because they contain a lot of irrelevant noise (and are too often been chameleonized). For instance, are you absolutely positive that for example this piece `<img src="resources/css/images/icon.png" alt="DX-57" />` is relevant to this particular problem? I.e. when you remove it, the problem disappears? No? Leave it out.

Comment: Ok, I will take a note. One idea why it's not working - I use form into another form. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Yes, a form cannot be inside another form. Sorry to say, but that's basic HTML. You should learn (or review) how the web works before start programming on the web. See this answer: [Where to start from in web development?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1843841/1065197) and  [Java web development, what skills do I need?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1958854/1065197), both by BalusC.

Comment: In my case what is the solution? How I can get the needed tabs functionality?

Comment: Any help please. I need some solution to solve the problem.

Comment: Why don't you use a library that already handle tabs like [primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabview.jsf) or [richfaces](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=tabPanel)?

Comment: For lazy loading again I need form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you pointed out in one of your comments, you cannot use nested forms. You need to restructure your layout. Place your outer form around your `<ul>`:

```
<h:panelGroup id="tabs" layout="block">
     <h:form prependId="false">
          <ul>
          ...
          </ul>
     </h:form>

     <c:forEach items="#{DatacenterProfileController.tabs}" var="tab">
          ...
     </c:forEach>
 </h:panelGroup>
```

The rest of you code should be OK. By this way you avoid nested forms.