# Spring Books: Which one to choose

Tags: spring

It may not be the exact category to place this query, 
but i could not found better than this. I request to
administrator(s) to handle this.

I am working on Spring framework since last one years.
But did not get involved in concepts, just use it as per project need.
Now i need to explore it as much as i can.
Please let me know which one is good to go with--
1. Spring In Action
2. Pro.Spring.3 by Clarence Ho and Rob Haroop
3. Spring Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach by Gary Mak

Or there any other book?

Thank You.

Comment: Didn't read them, but I like Manning's books, always got what I wanted with them, so I'd go for Spring in Action. But as I said, this is just a matter of experience with the editor, I didn't read it.

Comment: Do not forget the [Spring Framework Reference Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

Answer (score 2):

I read **Spring Recipes**, and I recommend it. It's clear, easy to follow, and covered everything I needed.

I actually started from Spring in Action and switched to recipes. It was just better organized, and more extensive.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for a better understanding of dependency injection per se. In that case I suggest you to read Manning's Dependency Injection http://www.manning.com/prasanna/. It uses Spring as example as well.