# h:inputTextarea Grabbing the text once the user has finished editing

Tags: jsp, jsf

I'm too new to JSF to understand how to dynamically grab the text within a `h:inputTextarea` and send it to a backing bean variable.  Do I need to do this in a form and specify a post or should I define a `f:param` within the `h"commandLink`?  I'm simply lost and searching stack has too many questions about too specific a problem to learn what to do.

Comment: @BalusC Referencing the previously asked question.  What should I do if I'm having issues with understanding the provided answer?

Comment: Take a step back and start here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1958808