# JSF2.2 <h:inputFile> problems

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jsf-2.2

I need your help, cause still can't make friends with ...
I read all of your posts about this topic,- now use tomcat 8.0.30, jsf 2.2 - choose in project facets, add jsf-impl 2.2.12 and jsf-api 2.2.12 in WEB-INF/lib and add these jars to project's build path, also add dependencies of these jars to pom.xml file!
import tag libs in page (try with jsp & xttml pages):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
```

and I have  in tags list, but it server don't use it, I have steel: "No tag "inputFile" defined in tag library imported with prefix "h""!
This page works ok without  tag (page validate username, password, email and insert 'em to mysql) & deploys on tomcat finely, it must upload files too. 
Share your knowledge, please! I'm not "nothing to do person", just very confused with it!

Comment: You're choosing the wrong namespaces. Go with the JSF 2.2 ones.

Comment: I replace 'em with xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html, but nothing - I have: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /home.jsp No tag "inputFile" defined in tag library imported with prefix "h"

Comment: Answer in the duplicate question clearly explains that you can't use JSF 2.2 tags in JSP, but only in Facelets. The answer also links to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info how to get started with JSF the correct way. There you can find in "Documentation" section essential links about minimum requirements, installing JSF and a Hello World. I however strongly recommend getting a real book as you already seem to lack the essential basics of Java EE web development in general and are just shooting around in the dark. This is not good. Start here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1958808