# Glassfish server does not start. NullPointeException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, glassfish, payara

I just downloaded the GlassFish 5.0 archive - Full Platform, unzipped it, I run it through the command line.

> asadmin start-domain

problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
```

I tried to set the path in the file **asenv.bat** -> **set path = C:/.../Java/bin** - did not help. Tried so to launch: **asadmin start-domain domain1** - did not help.

Installed: **jdk-9.0.1** Also tried on the 8th, did not help. What to do???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Are you seriously?? Please read my description!

Comment: I did already, that's why I'm saying `Possible` duplicate. Not `exact`

Comment: Like @Jonathan said, GlassFish 5 in not compatible with Java 9, for my case I was using GlassFish 5.1, Clear/Uninstall java 9 from your system and install Java 8. Make sure when you type java -version on command line the response you get is java 8 and not 9

Comment: Vifier Lockla provided the solution: you just need to specify which version of Java you want to use for Glassfih or Payara. I had the same issue for Payara server.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, Glassfish 5.1 doesn't exist for the moment. Continue with Glassfish 5.0 with this solution:

Just set the `AS_JAVA` variable in your `asenv.bat` file located here: `C:\DEVENV\glassfish5\glassfish\config`.

File to edit: add last line
[image: screenshot of code]

Relaunch your server....enjoy :
[image: screenshot of relaunch command to start your server]

Comment: That worked; but how you get there? what was the hint? it's sad, that such a popular server needs to be hacked to start.

Comment: @Vifier Lockla Should this work with replacing  jdk1.8.0_172 with jdk1.8.0_221 ? I tryed but didnt work for me. Even tried entering same thing in asenv.config but without the set before it.

Comment: for MacOS, update asenv.conf file => AS_JAVA=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_251.jdk/Contents/Home

Answer (score 12):

This looks to be this issue - https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22130.

GlassFish 5 does not work on JDK9, however GlassFish 6 works on JDK 11.

Comment: Damn! What a time waster... Wasted 10 minutes trying to figure out what exactly I did wrong...

Comment: This link has died since javaee was moved under the eclipse umbrella. Here is the new link. https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/glassfish/issues/22130

Comment: As of now, with 5.1, still not working out of the box (same exception)

Answer (score 9):

For me it didn't work what @Vifier Lockla did. I had to change the path/glassfish5/glassfish/config/asenv.conf file in a linux mint machine. At the bottom of the file the path of the jdk 1.8, i.e.

```
AS_JAVA="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_191"
```

Answer (score 3):

GlassFish 5.1 also not working with Java 9 or later versions.

glassfish 5.1 also needs java 8 with the AS_JAVA hack in asenv.conf/bat file.

Answer (score 2):

Edit asenv.bat put set AS_JAVA=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
and asenv.conf AS_JAVA="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle"

It works

Answer (score 1):

When you download the glassfish zip file from the internet and extract it.
Its a good practice to read the the readme file.
In my case the under the "prerequisites" title in the readme file, it specified: GlassFish 5.0 requires Oracle JDK 8 Update 144.
I downloaded and installed the JDK 8 update 144 as demanded. It worked instantly. I initially had JDK 14.0.2 and it was displaying the error @Aleksandr posted.

Answer (score 0):

I made the same mistake as the OP, because the release notes said specifically "GlassFish Server Open Source Edition Release 5.0 requires Oracle JDK 8 Update 144 or later" under heading **Required JDK Versions** in release notes.

However what you can do is drop down each version to see which is the latest jdk version that glassfish 5 will be compatible with Or Just download Java SE Development Kit 8 from https://www.oracle.com/in/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html.

You also have to add the java variable in asenv.bat as kindly commented by Vifier Lockla. Thanks to Vifier for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

for me I changed to the directory where glassfish is

**cd /opt**

then

**sudo glassfish5/bin/asadmin start-domain**

I am sure this works

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Mohd Zamri Bin Mat Jusoh 's answer,
I updated the javapath's symlinks as showed in
https://sjgpsoft.blogspot.com/2018/06/updating-oracle-javapath-symlinks-on.html

This error shows up when glassfish6 is on the user path, & glassfish5 is in the system path.