# Glassfish5 Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, ubuntu, glassfish

I have installed glassfish 5 in ubuntu and put it under the directory `/opt`, but when I typed `asadmin start-domain` I face this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.hk2.api.DynamicConfigurationService.createDynamicConfiguration()" because "dcs" is null
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)     
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)    
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)     
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)     
at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)   
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)   
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)     
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)  
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)    
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)    
at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Which JDK are you using? GF 5 only supports up to JDK 8 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Glassfish server does not start. NullPointeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458119/glassfish-server-does-not-start-nullpointeexception)

Comment: @ChristophJohn java -version ->  java version "15.0.2" 2021-01-19
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 15.0.2+7-27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 15.0.2+7-27, mixed mode, sharing  \n javac -version : javac 15.0.2
does these infos clarify the problem ?

Comment: Yes. See my comment and the comment from Jonathan.

Comment: @JonathanCoustick i did and i edit asevent.bat/conf but i didn't work the same problem occurs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Glassfish version 5 shows that behaviour when run with openjdk15 (at least in my machine)  I have configured (see below) it to run with JDK-8 and it starts correctly.

```
set JAVA_HOME="Your_path_to_jdk8"
set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%"
```

in windows, or

```
export JAVA_HOME="Your_path_to_jdk8"
export PATH="${JAVA_HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
```

in unix/linux.  Add this to the script you use to start it, so the environment directs Glassfish to the proper place to find java binaries.

Answer (score 3):

You have to put

set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_16

on this directory of you glassfish server:

C:\Users\Usuario\Documents\glassfish-5.0.1\glassfish5\glassfish\config\asenv

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with glassfish 6. Make sure you have JDK installed.

Also the glassfish documentation says you have to set JAVA_HOME environment variable an then the PATH variable to point to JAVA_HOME/bin.

On Linux I edited my `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib64/jvm/java-8-openjdk
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading form JDK 17 to JDK 8 worked. JDK 11 also didn't work.