# GlassFish 5.1.0 error because dcs is null

Tags: java, glassfish

Error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.hk2.api.DynamicConfigurationService.createDynamicConfiguration()" because "dcs" is null
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:128)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:120)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:194)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:200)
at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:64)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:193)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:207)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:347)
at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:282)
at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:33)
```

My `java -version:`

`java version 16.0.2 -- 2021-07-2020`

Project is also using `JDK` - `16.0.2`

GlassFish is using `JRE:` - `JDK` - `16.0.2`

I also did this:

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2" 
set PATH="%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%"
```

What can be problem? GF cant work with this jdk or jre?

Comment: your question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47458119/glassfish-server-does-not-start-nullpointeexception

Comment: And this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70686604/java-ee-glassfish-nullpointerexception-because-dcs-not-found

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the glassfish directory at this address glassfish5\glassfish\config, open the setenv file.bat with notepad and add there
set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251 (your path to java 8)