# Java EE Glassfish - NullPointerException because "dcs" not found

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, glassfish

Whent trying to run `asadmin` im getting this error:

```
/opt/glassfish5/bin $ ./asadmin start-domain
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.glassfish.hk2.api.DynamicConfigurationService.createDynamicConfiguration()" because "dcs" is null
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.initializeServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.newServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:144)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:218)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.common_impl.AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.createServiceLocator(AbstractModulesRegistryImpl.java:224)
    at com.sun.enterprise.module.single.StaticModulesRegistry.createServiceLocator(StaticModulesRegistry.java:88)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getServiceLocator(CLIContainer.java:217)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLIContainer.getLocalCommand(CLIContainer.java:255)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.getCommand(CLICommand.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.executeCommand(AdminMain.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain.doMain(AdminMain.java:306)
    at org.glassfish.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:57)
```

My Java JDK:

```
$ readlink -f $(which java)
/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

I've tried adding `AS_JAVA="/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"` to the `asenv.conf` file but the error persists. Any help?
Oh yeah, and it doesn't matter if im in `/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/bin` or `/opt/glassfish5/bin` the error is the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GlassFish 5 doesn’t support JDK 17, but the latest versions of GlassFish 6 do. If possible, try to upgrade to GlassFish 6.2.4, which is the current version at the time of writing.

Comment: Thank's for sharing, hopefully I won't use it in the future. I hate Java!

Comment: @Swagnar it's always good for yourself to avoid hating things ;) Goodluck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, **you need to use Java SDK 1.8** only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).