# <h:selectOneRadio> renders table element, how to avoid this?

Tags: jsf, html-table, selectoneradio

Is there a way to tell JSF that it should NOT render a `<table>` element when using `<h:selectOneRadio>`?
I don't use tables and it makes absolutely no sense in this case.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### JSF 2.3 with `group` attribute

As per [JSF spec issue 329](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-329) I have added a new `group` attribute to `<h:selectOneRadio>` which should make this all much less tedious. All radio button components having the same `group` value within a parent `UIForm` will be grouped with each other. Also they won't render any markup besides the radio button itself and the optional label if the select item has a non-null `label`. If any, the label appears directly after the radio button.

```
<!-- Just markup them the way you want! -->
<ul>
    <ui:repeat id="items" value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <li>
            <h:selectOneRadio group="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="#{item}" />
            </h:selectOneRadio>
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>
```

Following scenarios are also possible. When there are multiple components with same `group`, and the `value` attribute and/or `UISelectItem` child is absent, then it will reference those of the first component of the group.

```
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" />
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" />
```

```
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="one" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="two" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="three" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" />
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" />
```

```
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="one" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="two" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="three" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

```
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="one" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" value="#{otherBean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="two" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
<h:selectOneRadio group="foo" value="#{lastBean.selectedItem}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="three" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

It will be available in Mojarra as per 2.3.0-m07.

#### JSF 2.2 with passthrough elements

If you're on JSF 2.2 already, make use of its new [passthrough elements/attribtues](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm) feature whereby you explicitly set the `name` attribute as a passthrough attribute. In order to set the submitted value in the model, you only need an additional `<h:inputHidden>`.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">

...

<!-- Just markup them the way you want! -->
<ul>
    <ui:repeat id="items" value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <li>
            <input type="radio" jsf:id="item" a:name="#{hiddenItem.clientId}"
                value="#{item}" a:checked="#{item eq bean.selectedItem ? 'checked' : null}" />
            <h:outputLabel for="item" value="#{item}" />
        </li>
    </ui:repeat>
</ul>

<!-- This one won't display anything. -->
<h:inputHidden id="selectedItem" binding="#{hiddenItem}" value="#{bean.selectedItem}"
    rendered="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal ne 6}" />
```

In depth technical explanation can be found in this blog: [Custom layout with h:selectOneRadio in JSF 2.2](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/custom-layout-with-hselectoneradio-in.html).

#### PrimeFaces (JSF 2.x)

If you happen to use [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org), then you can also use [`<p:selectOneRadio layout="custom">`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml) with `<p:radioButton>`.

```
<html ... xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<!-- This one won't display anything. -->
<p:selectOneRadio id="foo" value="#{bean.selectedFoo}" layout="custom">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableFoos}" />
</p:selectOneRadio>

<!-- Just markup them the way you want! -->
<ul>
    <li><p:radioButton for="foo" itemIndex="0" /></li>
    <li><p:radioButton for="foo" itemIndex="1" /></li>
    <li><p:radioButton for="foo" itemIndex="2" /></li>
</ul>
```

You can also loop over the available items, you only need to do it during [view build time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense):

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach items="#{bean.availableFoos}" varStatus="loop">
        <li><p:radioButton for="foo" itemIndex="#{loop.index}" /></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

#### Tomahawk (JSF 1.x or 2.x)

If you're not on JSF 2.2 yet or if you don't like PrimeFaces UI, grab [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/index.html) [`<t:selectOneRadio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html) which renders the same plain HTML output as `<h:selectOneRadio>`, but supports a `layout="spread"` attribute so that you can position the items by [`<t:radio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_radio.html) the way you want.

E.g.

```html
<html ... xmlns:t="http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk">

<!-- This one won't display anything. -->
<t:selectOneRadio id="foo" value="#{bean.selectedFoo}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableFoos}" />
</t:selectOneRadio>

<!-- Just markup them the way you want! -->
<ul>
    <li><t:radio for="foo" index="0" /></li>
    <li><t:radio for="foo" index="1" /></li>
    <li><t:radio for="foo" index="2" /></li>
</ul>
```

#### Custom Renderer

Supply a custom [`Renderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html). It's only a bit of work. Start at the first "See also" link shown below:

#### See also:

- [How to override h:selectOneRadio renderer? Where is the renderer class in jsf-impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389352/how-to-override-hselectoneradio-renderer-where-is-the-renderer-class-in-jsf-im/)
- [Is it possible to use JSF to build clean CSS layouts without using tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867605/is-it-possible-to-use-jsf-to-build-clean-css-layouts-without-using-tables)
- [Render selectManyCheckbox without HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607967/render-selectmanycheckbox-without-html-table)

Comment: In your second PrimeFaces solution (the one with the forEach), how would you add labels to the radio buttons? I can't seem to get the id of the respective `input` elements to reference in a `h:outputLabel` element.

Comment: @jessepeng: use e.g. `id="foo_#{loop.index}"`. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3342984

Comment: Using that approach, only the enclosing div of the radio button is referenced, like this: `<div id="cQueryEditor:opt_2" class="ui-radiobutton ui-radiobutton-native ui-widget">...</div>
<label for="cQueryEditor:opt_2">...</label>`. Btw, I'm using PrimeFaces' plain style.

Comment: I downloaded this implementation:https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.13 but I can not find the taglib.xml file for namespace: passthrough. Only compsoite, facelets, html_basic, jstl-core jstl-fn, mojarra_ext and ui is here. Where should the passthrough be?

Comment: @Koray: That namespace doesn't have any tags/functions in first place.

Comment: @BausC Interesting. How does Facelets processor resolve and process this namespace?

Comment: @Koray: it's built into `TagDecorator`: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/view/facelets/TagDecorator.html

Comment: Should thisork wirh a 'dynamic' group too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58521146/hselectoneradio-group-problem-within-nested-uirepeat-elements  Seems to cause a problem

Answer (score 2):

i don't know if it's reasonable enough for you but, here is a sample work-around.

xhtml code:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.valueList}" var="radioValue">
    <input type="radio" name="radioSelection" value="#{radioValue}" checked="#{radioValue == myBean.selectedRadioValue ? 'checked' : ''}">#{radioValue}</input>
</ui:repeat>
```

backing bean:

```
    private String selectedRadioValue;

    private List<Integer> valueList;

    public MyBean() {
        valueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            valueList.add(i);
        }
    }

    public String getSelectedRadioValue() {
        return selectedRadioValue;
    }

    public List<Integer> getValueList() {
        return valueList;
    }

    public void actionMethod() {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
        selectedRadioValue = request.getParameter("radioSelection");
    }
```

since you cannot assign a value to the radio selection directly on xhtml, you need to get it from request parameters and assign it manually within your action method.