# SelectOneRadio generated html table

Tags: html, css, jsf, jsf-2, selectoneradio

I'm using JSF 2 and the h:selectOneRadio component that renders all the inputs inside a table tbody, tr, td...

Is there a way to generate divs instead of this table rows and columns in order to use a previously designed html and css page for this items?

Example:

I have this structure for items:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <label for="mob-100" class="fancyradio">
        <input type="radio" name="config-mob" id="movil-100" class="radio01 hide-item">
        </input>                                                    
        <span>My item</span>                                            
    </label>
</div>
```

And the component is generating this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="j_idt27" id="j_idt27:0" value="12">
                <label for="j_idt27:0" class="active"> My item</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
.
.
.   
     </tbody>
</table>
```

I'll need to adapt the first structure to the generated selectoneradio html.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jsf 2.0 <h:selectOneRadio> renders table element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435039/jsf-2-0-hselectoneradio-renders-table-element)

Comment: Or, use PrimeFaces `<p:selectOneRadio>` which generates `<div><ul><li>` so that you've to rewrite CSS only.