# Add styling to label generated by selectOneRadio

Tags: css, jsf, label, selectoneradio

How to add `radio-inline control-label` style classes to the label generated by this code?

```
<h:selectOneRadio>
    <f:selectItem itemValue="0" itemLabel="Male" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Female" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`enabledClass` and `disabledClass`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/selectOneRadio.html) attributes  for this. They will be applied on the rendered label. Assuming that you don't have disabled items, this should do.

```
<h:selectOneRadio enabledClass="radio-inline">
    ...
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

An alternative is to redefine the CSS selector as follows in order to select and style the labels.

```
<h:selectOneRadio styleClass="radio-inline">
    ...
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

```css
.radio-inline label {
    ...
}
```

A completely different alternative is to manually customize the radio buttons, see also [<h:selectOneRadio> renders table element, how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435039/hselectoneradio-renders-table-element-how-to-avoid-this)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to add class to the Labels of selectOneRadio

```
<h:selectOneRadio disabledClass ="radio-inline" enabledClass ="radio-inline">
```

Comment: Thank you! Those are good hidden. The other answer has been fixed.