# How to override h:selectOneRadio renderer? Where is the renderer class in jsf-impl?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to override renderer used by `<h:selectOneRadio>`? I tried to find the class from jsf-impl package of JSF 2.2 but didn't find it. The reason I want to do this is to get rid of the table it generates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Is it possible to override renderer used by h:selectOneRadio?*

Yes, surely it is. Otherwise, UI component libraries like PrimeFaces couldn't exist.

---

> *I tried to find the class from jsf-impl package but didn't find it.*

The exact class depends on the JSF implementation you're using. If it's Mojarra, then it's the [`com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.sun.faces/jsf-impl/2.2.0/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/RadioRenderer.java#RadioRenderer) class. If it's MyFaces, then it's the [`org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlRadioRenderer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.myfaces.core/myfaces-impl/2.1.12/org/apache/myfaces/renderkit/html/HtmlRadioRenderer.java#HtmlRadioRenderer) class.

In order to properly override it, just extend the class and override methods where necessary and register it as follows in your `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>javax.faces.SelectOne</component-family>
        <renderer-type>javax.faces.Radio</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>com.example.MyRadioRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

Keep in mind that you're this way tight-coupling the renderer to the specific JSF impl/version. Such an extended renderer is not compatible with a different JSF implementation (i.e. your app wouldn't deploy when you ever replace Mojarra by MyFaces) and may possibly break when the current JSF implementation has been updated to a newer version. If you worry about this, consider writing the renderer entirely from scratch, like PrimeFaces et.al. do.

---

> *The reason I want to do this is to get rid of the table it generates.*

Consider looking at [Tomahawk](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk/) or [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org) instead of reinventing the wheel. They have respectively a [`<t:selectOneRadio layout="spread"><t:radio>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_selectOneRadio.html) and [`<p:selectOneRadio layout="custom"><p:radioButton>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneRadio.xhtml) which allows you positioning those things everywhere you want.

#### See also:

- [<h:selectOneRadio> renders table element, how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435039/jsf-2-0-hselectoneradio-renders-table-element/)

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
  <render-kit>
        <renderer>
            <component-family>javax.faces.SelectOne</component-family>
            <renderer-type>javax.faces.Radio</renderer-type>
            <renderer-class>com.sial.ecommerce.configurator.ui.model.RadioRendererWithoutDataTable</renderer-class>
        </renderer>
    </render-kit>
```

to `faces-config.xml`.

And created a class which extends `com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer` And I did override the method `encodeEnd`  then commented out the code which adding `table` elements.

```
public class RadioRendererWithoutDataTable extends com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.RadioRenderer {
    @Override
    public void encodeEnd(FacesContext context, UIComponent component) throws IOException {

        rendererParamsNotNull(context, component);

        if (!shouldEncode(component)) {
            return;
        }

        ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();
        assert (writer != null);

        String alignStr;
        Object borderObj;
        boolean alignVertical = false;
        int border = 0;

        if (null != (alignStr = (String) component.getAttributes().get("layout"))) {
            alignVertical = alignStr.equalsIgnoreCase("pageDirection");
        }
        if (null != (borderObj = component.getAttributes().get("border"))) {
            border = (Integer) borderObj;
        }

        Converter converter = null;
        if (component instanceof ValueHolder) {
            converter = ((ValueHolder) component).getConverter();
        }

//      renderBeginText(component, border, alignVertical, context, true);

        Iterator<SelectItem> items = RenderKitUtils.getSelectItems(context, component);

        Object currentSelections = getCurrentSelectedValues(component);
        Object[] submittedValues = getSubmittedSelectedValues(component);
        Map<String, Object> attributes = component.getAttributes();
        OptionComponentInfo optionInfo = new OptionComponentInfo((String) attributes.get("disabledClass"),
                (String) attributes.get("enabledClass"), (String) attributes.get("unselectedClass"),
                (String) attributes.get("selectedClass"), Util.componentIsDisabled(component), isHideNoSelection(component));
        int idx = -1;
        while (items.hasNext()) {
            SelectItem curItem = items.next();
            idx++;
            // If we come across a group of options, render them as a nested
            // table.
            if (curItem instanceof SelectItemGroup) {
                // write out the label for the group.
                if (curItem.getLabel() != null) {
//                  if (alignVertical) {
//                      writer.startElement("tr", component);
//                  }
                    //writer.startElement("td", component);
                    writer.writeText(curItem.getLabel(), component, "label");
//                  writer.endElement("td");
//                  if (alignVertical) {
//                      writer.endElement("tr");
//                  }

                }
//              if (alignVertical) {
//                  writer.startElement("tr", component);
//              }
//              writer.startElement("td", component);
//              writer.writeText("\n", component, null);
//              renderBeginText(component, 0, alignVertical, context, false);
                // render options of this group.
                SelectItem[] itemsArray = ((SelectItemGroup) curItem).getSelectItems();
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.length; ++i) {
                    renderOption(context, component, converter, itemsArray[i], currentSelections, submittedValues, alignVertical, i,
                            optionInfo);
                }
//              renderEndText(component, alignVertical, context);
//              writer.endElement("td");
//              if (alignVertical) {
//                  writer.endElement("tr");
//                  writer.writeText("\n", component, null);
//              }
            } else {
                renderOption(context, component, converter, curItem, currentSelections, submittedValues, alignVertical, idx, optionInfo);
            }
        }

        //renderEndText(component, alignVertical, context);
    }
```

Then it worked for me.

When I given

```
<h:selectOneRadio >
<f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Item 1" />
<f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="Item 2" />
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

in my jsf page.

It converted to

```
<input type="radio" name="bulkForm:j_idt224" id="bulkForm:j_idt224:0" value="1"><label for="bulkForm:j_idt224:0"> Item 1</label>

<input type="radio" name="bulkForm:j_idt224" id="bulkForm:j_idt224:1" value="2"><label for="bulkForm:j_idt224:1"> Item 2</label>
```

which was what I need.