# How to specify the type of wrapper for JSF custom component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I need to create the custom component as SelectOneRadio, but it should not has wrapper `<table>` But, `<ul>, <li>` for example. How I can specify the type of wrapper, ul, table or something else, when creating JSF custom components?[image: HtmlSelectOneRadio example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a conceptual misunderstanding. There's no such thing as "wrapper" in this context. HTML is just generated by the [`Renderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/render/Renderer.html) associated with the [`UIComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html). If you'd like to change the generated HTML representation, just supply your own custom `Renderer`.

That said, it's advisable to learn JSF by a [decent book](https://jsf.zeef.com/bauke.scholtz#block_72) so that you get the basic concepts properly right from the beginning on. Creating custom components is already covered in such a book.

#### See also:

- [How to override h:selectOneRadio renderer? Where is the renderer class in jsf-impl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18389352/how-to-override-hselectoneradio-renderer-where-is-the-renderer-class-in-jsf-im/)
- [How do I determine the renderer of a built-in component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831294/how-do-i-determine-the-renderer-of-a-built-in-component/)

Comment: I meant wrapper as not java or JSF definition. But thank you for advice, I feel the realy knowledge gap. As always great answer, @BalusC, thank you :)