# Render selectManyCheckbox without HTML table

Tags: jsf-2, checkbox

is there a way to remove the table out of rendered html that is created by the `h:selectManyCheckbox` tag in server faces?

I am using twitter bootstrap and i placed the checkboxes inside a dropdown menu:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-form">
    <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" />
            Activated
    </label></li>
    <li><label class="checkbox"> <input type="checkbox" />
            Deactivated
    </label></li>
</ul>
```

So the generated html table destroys the layout ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just render a bunch of `<h:outputLabel><h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` inside `<ui:repeat>`. This way you've markup freedom. You'll only need to alter the model from e.g. `List<T>` to `Map<T, Boolean>` to represent the checked values and then loop over the map afterwards to collect checked ones.

A ready-to-use component is Tomahawk's [`<t:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_selectManyCheckbox.html) which has an additional `layout` attribute value of `spread`.