# JSF change how f:selectItem renders

Tags: spring, jsf

I have a tag h:selectManyCheckbox, in it a loop over a list. for each item in the list I need a checkbox. Unfortunately the format of the checkbox + label does not correspond to the table which jsf creates. I need a div around each item, like this:

```
<div class="form_control var_checkbox">custom 
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="service" id="service_0" data-product="additional_price" data-product-add-price="100.0">
    <label class="label" for="service_0">title</label>
    <span class="guarantee_price">CHF 100.0</span>
</div>
```

but jsf renders it like this:

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><input id="addToCart:j_id_29_2:0" type="checkbox" name="addToCart:j_id_29_2" value="0"><label for="addToCart:j_id_29_2:0">&nbsp;title</label></td>
         <td><input id="addToCart:j_id_29_2:1" type="checkbox" name="addToCart:j_id_29_2" value="1"><label for="addToCart:j_id_29_2:1">&nbsp;titel2</label></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

here's the code currently generating it:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="${addToCartBean.selectedServicesIndexes}">
    <c:forEach items="#{productServicesJSFBean.productServicePlusBeanKeySet}" var="productServicePlusKey">
        <c:forEach items="#{productServicesJSFBean.productServicePlusBeans[productServicePlusKey]}" var="productServicePlus">
            <div class="form_control var_checkbox">
                <f:selectItem itemValue="${counter}" itemLabel="${productServicePlus.servicePlusDisplay.title}" >custom </f:selectItem>
            </div>
            <c:set var="counter" value="${counter + 1}"/>
        </c:forEach>
    </c:forEach>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

I tried creating the checkbox by hand, but jsf doesnt pick it up. We can not use a table, it has to be in the div format. How can I change how jsf renders those selectItems. I dont want it globally, only for those here. How can I do that?

Comment: did you try to place your code with "desired output" in a `ui:repeat`? that way, you can make the page render anything you like. store the true/false selections in a `HashMap<object, boolean>` behind, keyed with your service ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone I sent this question to sent me this SO question, which I didnt find through google: [Render selectManyCheckbox without HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607967/render-selectmanycheckbox-without-html-table) . got it working with `<h:outputLabel><h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`