# How to put a label beside HtmlSelectOneRadio programatically

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want to put a label beside the radio button.

[image]

`HtmlSelectOneRadio` has a `setLabel(String s)` method. But it does not work.

Is there a way to do that without using another library?

Comment: Ah, the eternal question . [Use `<t:selectOneRadio>` instead, or write a custom renderer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435039/jsf-2-0-hselectoneradio-renders-table-element/7435111#7435111). By the way, if you do as if you're defining the view in a normal JSP/Facelets file like everyone, then it should be easier to find answers. There's namely **nothing** which is impossible in JSP/Facelets and only possible in Java. If you've found the answer for JSP/Facelets file, then you should be easily able to port it to Java.

Comment: Hi @BalusC ! Tks for the response. The project is using jsf-facelets version 1.1.15. Is there any problem including the tomahawk dependency?

Comment: HI @BalusC. I changed the question. I want to print a label beside the radio button, no matter if it's a div or a table. I think the warning about duplicate could be removed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is done by using the **setItemLabel** in the **UISelectItem** object.

Then using some css to let it the way you want.

```
UISelectItem selectItemSim = new UISelectItem();
        UISelectItem selectItemNao = new UISelectItem();
        selectItemSim.setItemLabel("SIM");
        selectItemSim.setItemValue("SIM");
        selectItemSim.setId(perguntaVO.getCodigo() + "SIM");
        selectItemNao.setItemValue("NAO");
        selectItemNao.setItemLabel("NÃO");
        selectItemNao.setId(perguntaVO.getCodigo() + "NAO");
        htmlOneRadio.getChildren().add(selectItemSim);
        htmlOneRadio.getChildren().add(selectItemNao);
```