# Preset checked state of h:selectOneRadio with passthrough elements

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, selectoneradio, passthrough-elements

I am trying to implement the solution described in 
[<h:selectOneRadio> renders table element, how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435039/hselectoneradio-renders-table-element-how-to-avoid-this/7435111#7435111)

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h:outputLabel styleClass="control-label"
        value="#{msgClient.legalPersonality} " />
    Selected value : <h:outputText value="#{msgClient['legalPersonality.' += clientBean.clientDto.legalPersonality.label]}" />
    <div>                                       
        <f:metadata>
            <f:viewParam name="legalPersonality" value="#{clientBean.clientDto.legalPersonality}" />
        </f:metadata>
        <ui:repeat var="legalPersonality" value="#{clientBean.legalPersonalities}">
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <input type="radio" jsf:id="legal" pt:name="legalPersonality" value="#{legalPersonality}">
                    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" />
                </input> 
                <h:outputText value="#{msgClient['legalPersonality.' += legalPersonality.label]}" />
            </label>                                        
        </ui:repeat>
    </div>
</div>
```

Everything seems to work fine, the selected value is correctly updated with the f:ajax component (setter is called with the correct value) BUT radio buttons are never checked. I mean it is checked when I click on it but it goes unchecked immediatly after. Even at page load, with a default value in clientDto.legalPersonality, everything is unchecked.

How it looks like : http://oi58.tinypic.com/242788g.jpg

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, the example in the question you found was a bit too oversimplified. It was missing the `checked` attribute which is necessary in order to preset the current selection on page load and/or after ajax render as in your case. In HTML, the checked state of a radio button is achieved by setting the `checked` attribute.

You can use `<f:passThroughAttribute>` to set the `checked` attribute, whereby you make sure that you set `#{null}` in unchecked case, so that it wouldn't render the `checked` attribute at all. It's namely a minimized attribute; even if we used `checked="false"`, HTML would still consider it checked.

```
<input type="radio" jsf:id="legal" pt:name="legalPersonality" value="#{legalPersonality}">
    <f:passThroughAttribute name="checked" value="#{legalPersonality eq clientBean.clientDto.legalPersonality ? 'checked' : null}" />
    <f:ajax execute="@this" render="@form" />
</input>
```

The example in the question you found has in the meanwhile been updated. Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thank you for your help.