# JSF binding doesn't work for <input type="radio"

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I created a jsf component which displays for an "answer" model the proper html control. 
There exists single choice and multiple choice as answertype. 
For the answertype multiply choice I can use

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.selectedByUser}" />
```

The binding works.
For the answertype I can't use the

At the moment I'm using

```
 <input type="radio" name="answer#{cc.attrs.QuestionId}" value="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.selectedByUser}" />
```

but when the user selects it, the binding doesn't seem to work. After the post the corresponding selectedByUser is still false.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Would it be possible to retrieve the form data in the bean and assign it to model?

[Edit]
My Question and Answer component looks something like this:

Question:

```
<cc:interface>
  <cc:attribute name="ItemSource" type="code.elephant.domainmodel.Question" required="true" />
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
<c:forEach items="${cc.attrs.ItemSource.answers}" var="item">
  <li>
    <local:Answer ItemSource="#{item}" AnswerType="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.answerType}" 
                  GapString="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.gapString}"
                  QuestionId="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.questionId}"/>
  </li> 
</c:forEach>
```

Answer:

```
<!-- INTERFACE -->
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="AnswerType" type="code.elephant.domainmodel.AnswerType" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="ItemSource" type="code.elephant.domainmodel.Answer" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="QuestionId" type="java.lang.Long" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="GapString" type="java.lang.String" />
</cc:interface>

<!-- IMPLEMENTATION -->
<cc:implementation>
<c:if test="#{cc.attrs.AnswerType == 'MultipleChoice'}">
  <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.selectedByUser}" />
  <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.text}"  />
</c:if>
<c:if test="#{cc.attrs.AnswerType == 'SingleChoice'}">
  <input type="radio" name="answer#{cc.attrs.QuestionId}" value="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.selectedByUser}" />#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.text}
</c:if>
</cc:implementation>
```

Comment: JSF has no knowledge of this input: `<input type="radio" name="answer#{cc.attrs.QuestionId}" value="#{cc.attrs.ItemSource.selectedByUser}" />` it is in no way a jsf componebnt/input. Why do you want to use it that way? why not use the jsf `h:selectOneRadio`?

Comment: You could make use of the 'html5 friendly' markup if you really need it like you do: http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/custom-layout-with-hselectoneradio-in.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [<h:selectOneRadio> renders table element, how to avoid this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7435039/hselectoneradio-renders-table-element-how-to-avoid-this)

Comment: I can't use  `<h:selectOneRadio...` because the `<f:selectItem` would be the Answer object it self. Thats why the html5 approache also doesn't work here.

Comment: I want to assign the ` <input type="radio" value=""` in my composite component to the bound model. Which methods do I have to override? @Kukeltje