jsf conditional checked attribute using passthrough not working
I am trying to use the jsf passthrough to conditionally add the checked attribute to radio buttons.  It is not working.  The checked attribute gets added to the radio button even when the condition returns null.  Below is a test I did.  What am I doing wrong here?
      <h:inputHidden id="testHidden" binding="#{testHidden}" value="1"/>
      <input type="radio" a:checked="#{testHidden.value eq '1' ? 'checked' : null}" jsf:id="test1" name="test1" value="1"/>
      <input type="radio" a:checked="#{testHidden.value eq '2' ? 'checked' : null}" jsf:id="test2" name="test2" value="2"/>


Below is the HTML they produced:
    <input type="hidden" id="viewDevicesSearchForm:testHidden" name="viewDevicesSearchForm:testHidden" value="1">
    <input id="viewDevicesSearchForm:test1" name="test1" checked="checked" type="radio" value="1">
    <input id="viewDevicesSearchForm:test2" name="test2" checked="" type="radio" value="2">

I am expected test2 element to have no checked attribute, but it has it with a value of "".
Note: I am using myfaces 3.x.

Just use <h:selectOneRadio> then?

@BalusC I need my radio button in custom layout.  I follow this excellent post from you "https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/custom-layout-with-hselectoneradio-in.html".  It works great. But I just can't get this checked attribute to work.

That's possible since JSF 2.3 with new <h:selectOneRadio group> attribute. You're apparently already using JSF 3.0. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/7435039. Your approach is for JSF 2.2 or older as seen on my blog https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/custom-layout-with-hselectoneradio-in.html which worked in Mojarra. Apparently MyFaces renderer has a bug that it renders the attribute anyway when associated value is null.
